# Unix command equivalent in Windows Powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line

what is the equivalent of command  `ls -la` in Windows Powershell?

Comment: `Get-Command ls | Get-Help`. In PowerShell you can use `ls` as an alias to `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Help` to learn how to use it.

Comment: @Clijsters since this is some kind of unix question, the `-full` for Get-Help will mimic a man page a lot better ;) 
`Get-Command  ls | Get-Help -full` or shorter and paged: `help -full ls`

Comment: More funny is, that I'm using `ls` in my example and told you to not use `ls` in your example... Now i'm confused if I'm wrong

Answer (score 4):

`Get-ChildItem -Force` will reveal hidden items, but the format of `-la` isn't directly mirror-able in powershell though as it returns objects rather than a string, use `Select x,y,z` to get the details you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not in correct order for the `-l`-switch, but this will get you started:

```
ls -force|Select-Object attributes, fullname, length, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, @{N='Owner';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}}|Format-Table
```

To see which properties are available for `select-object` you can use the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -force|Get-Member -MemberType Properties
```

And as stated by Clijsters in the comments: If you are using linux, `ls` might not be an valid Powershell alias, so use `Get-ChildItem` or `gci`.

Comment: I'd suggest to not use `ls` in your example, because on PowerShell in linux, lt isn't an Alias to `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: @Clijsters Thanks for the hint, added some more info.